# I am having trouble setting a GIF in an embed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

I currently have a list of gifs in a list in a different python file(I don't know how to use json) and I have for an embed `embed.set_image(url=random.choice(gifs.gifs)`(gifs being the python file and list). When this happens, you can see the outline of an image but it is blank. How may I resolve this?

Comment: What happens when you print `random.choice(gifs.gifs)`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything works for me.
You can try using my code. But if it doesn't work either could you send your code to review it?

Gif Command:

```
@bot.command("gif")
async def send_gif(ctx: commands.Context):
    import gifs
    embed = Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=random.choice(gifs.gifs))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Gifs.py File:

```
gifs = [
    "https://media1.giphy.com/media/25oFarLxPqrNS/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47x28vl8dmq3zcn3471yorivulan62t8hbpdzg0q7f&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g",
    "https://media1.giphy.com/media/hpW93QfcSkzHa/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47x28vl8dmq3zcn3471yorivulan62t8hbpdzg0q7f&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g"
]
```